# Moq Unit tests for Redis Cache

Tags: c#, unit-testing, redis, moq, stackexchange.redis

I have the following implementation.
I want to write unit tests for these by mocking, as i don't want to provide any connection strings.

```
  public virtual void Put<TValue>(string key, TValue value, TimeSpan? timeout)
        {           
            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
            if (Config.CacheEnableCompression)
            {
                this.Cache.StringSet(key, Compressor.GZipCompress(serialized), timeout ?? DefaultExpiration);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Cache.StringSet(key, serialized, timeout ?? DefaultExpiration);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the type of the Cache/Config objects?

Comment: @Seb String type

Comment: @Seb So basically Config is the configuration manager and Cache is derived from connectionmultiplexer.getdatabase()

Comment: Can you share the declaration of `Cache` and `Config` in the class? How are you initializing them?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya     private IDatabase Cache => this._connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase();

Comment: So you need to create mock of both `_connectionMultiplexer` and of whatever is being returned by `GetDatabase` method of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could mock the multiplexer and the database objects like this:

```
var mockDatabase = new Mock<StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase>();

var mockMultiplexer = new Mock<StackExchange.Redis.IConnectionMultiplexer>();

mockMultiplexer
    .Setup(_ => _.GetDatabase(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
    .Returns(mockDatabase.Object);
```